# Sort Blank cells to bottom in a descending sort using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula

I am sorting the following columns independently and in descending order, i.e. the largest value in each column will always be in the top row. However, I have several blank cells in the table.

These are not actually blank, but rather the index/match formula references another formula cell `IFERROR(H2/I2,"")` that gives a blank answer. I wish to sort the blank cells at the bottom of each column when performing the descending sort.

How can I amend the following VBA code to allow for this? I would prefer the solution to be more generic, and also take care of the situation whereby I am sorting both positive and negative numbers in the filled cells in descending order.

```
Sub SortIndividualCol()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim yRg As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range Selection:", _
                                    Title:="Input header range", Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each yRg In xRg
        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=yRg, Order:=xlDescending
            .SetRange ws.Range(yRg, yRg.End(xlDown))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Apply
        End With
    Next yRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Before sorting:

[image: Data before sorting]

After descending sort, but blank cells are sorted to the top:

[image: Data after descending sort, but blank cells are sorted to the top:]

Comment: Would you entertain using a helper column that has a formula in it?

Comment: Hi @braX, yup I don't mind adding new columns if that solves the sorting issue. The other constraint is that I would prefer a more generic solution that takes care of the case whereby I am sorting both negative and positive numbers in descending order. I have edited this in my question

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic loop that will loop and sort each column independently. ***Disclaimer*** Row data integrity will not be maintained.

```
For x = 1 To 5 'adjust to the number of columns you want to sort
    With ActiveSheet.Sort 'I prefer to use the actual sheet name
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add .Parent.Columns(x), Order:=xlDescending
        .SetRange .SetRange .Parent.Cells(1, x).Resize(6) 'you can use a last row variable -1
        .Apply
    End With
Next x
```